# Is "substract" (versus "subtract") a proper word?

Tags: word-choice, errors

I read an article recently where the author used "substract" instead of "subtract".  I'm more familiar with the latter word but after doing a bit of googling, it seems that both words are being used, although "subtract" seems more mainstream than the other. Which of the two is more appropriate? Is "substract" even acceptable?

Comment: How about some old text books on mathematics/arithmetic? I feel I have something to say on this. Did they use substract, with the additional "s"?

Comment: @Kris: As old dictionaries show (see my answer), "substract" was already considered erroneous and obsolete in 1891 and 1913. So you'd have to consider books much older than that, if at all.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I did not mean *that* old! I'm sure it existed in the sixties though I could not dig up any references.

Comment: '*substract*' sounds better, but we are more familiar with '*subtract*' so this creates confusion which should not be there.

Comment: @vicks: I think *subtract* sounds better. Maybe the entire mathematical world should go to war over this. =)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

"Subtract" is the word. Though the obsolete word "substract" *did* exist, any occurrence you see these days is most likely just a common mistake, formed by analogy either with "abstract" or with other languages whose corresponding words do have two ‘s’s.

Many recent dictionaries do not list "substract". Of "substract", the [*Century Dictionary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_Dictionary) (1891) [said](http://www.wordnik.com/words/substract):

> 1. An erroneous form of **subtract**, common in vulgar use.

*Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary* of 1913 [called it](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/WEBSTER.sh?WORD=substract) "obsolete", while the even older version of 1828 [said](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=Substract&quicksearch=on)

> Note.--Substract was formerly used in analogy with abstract. But in modern usage, it is written according to the Latin, subtract. See this word and its derivatives.

Additionally, I know people who find "substract" very annoying. :-)

Comment: It is annoying, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't claim to be one of them. ;-)

Comment: I'm probably one of them though. XD

Comment: last two links are broken!

Comment: Apparently I don't have sufficient rep to post, but according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/substraction), _substraction_ does have a legitimate history, as well as a secondary, non-mathematical sense. It also cites a different etymology than those given in other answers (without reference), here: "Medieval Latin _substraction-_, _substractio_, from Late Latin _substractus_." Would be nice to see word lovers role model tolerance, curiosity & appreciation of differences...

Answer (score 19):

It seems that the usage of "substract" is linguistically incorrect. However, I disagree about explaining this usage as a "showing-off". It seems that other languages do contain the letter "s" as in "soustraction" in French. People with a multi-lingual background are more likely to make mistakes, and it is nice if we just point that out to them without prejudice.

Comment: But that's because "sous" means "sub". "Souterrain" must've lobbed it off to make it sound better.

Comment: .. because "souterrain" is a composed word from "sous" and "terrain" where "sous" has its last letter '-s' mute.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman That is probably true. In old texts souterrain is written as soûtterain, where the circumflex indicates the lobbed-off 's'.
Also, the correct word "substrate" might cause additional confusion.

Answer (score 16):

French people use "substract" mistakingly a lot because in french, the word is "soustraction", which contains the sound "s" inside.

Comment: Same in Spanish and Galician at least. We tend to assume that "substract" is correct because of "sustraer" in our language. English "subtract", Spanish "sustraer" and French "soustraire" share a common root, but an epenthetic "s" was probably added for the Latin-derived languages at some point.

Comment: I'm surprised a completely unsubstantiated statement like this is not flagged or removed by moderators... This is nothing more than a plausible generalization, but hardly useful.

Answer (score 8):

If *sub**s**tract* is incorrect according to established English usage, this is only because English usage derives this verb from Latin *subtraho* ‘to subtract’, which excludes the *‑s‑*.

In many a Romance language — for example, in Spanish — it derives from the Latin prefix *sub‑* coupled with the Latin verb *extraho* ‘to extract’; hence Spanish [*sub**s**traer*](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=substraer).  You say *‘sub-tract’* in English where in Spanish we say *‘sub-**ex**tract’*; hence the extra *s*.

*Substract* is incorrect in English, but it could equally have been correct if imported differently.

Comment: Is "ex" actually the source of this s, or is it possibly just epenthetic like the s in "abstract"?

Comment: @herisson RAE dictionary mention that *substraer* originates from late latin *substrahĕre*. Interestingly now *sustraer* is the word in the latest dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of "substract" and, more to the point, neither has my edition of the Oxford English Dictionary. Even if it is a word, assuming that it means the same as "subtract" I can't see any point in preferring it over the better known word, apart from showing off.

Answer (score 2):

I found the word "substract" in a memoir written by an old Boston lady in the 1920s, describing how she as a child (during the 1850s) pilfered newspapers from her mother's cache and was able to trade them for candy. I like this usage, as it conveys a kind of arch, sneaky tone better than either "extract" or "subtract" But it's not mathematical at all.

Comment: Interestingly, the word "abstract" is itself used in such a sense: to pull out something, or even to pilfer.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the etymology, we can see that "substract" is erroneous.  "subtract" is derived from a the Latin compound verb "subtraho", whose supine is "subtractum".  There is no form "substraho" of this verb.